# Преобразовать Polygon в Image

Tags: java, javafx, изображения, polygon

Можно ли в JavaFx сделать преобразование массива `Polygon` в класс `Image`. Либо как-то сохранять их сразу в png, не пользуясь `Snapshot`. 
Надо преобразовать массив полигонов, не выводя их на экран, в Image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`snapshot()` все-же использовать придется:

```
package example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.embed.swing.JFXPanel;
import javafx.embed.swing.SwingFXUtils;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.image.WritableImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new JFXPanel(); // - простой способ инициализировать Toolkit

        Platform.runLater(() -> {
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(50, 50);
            GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();
            gc.fillPolygon(new double[]{10, 40, 25}, new double[]{40, 40, 10}, 3);

            WritableImage image = canvas.snapshot(null, null);
            File file = new File("polygon.png");
            try {
                ImageIO.write(SwingFXUtils.fromFXImage(image, null), "png", file);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

    }
}
```